# What makes a cursor appear on a textbox or a dynamic textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, focus

I have a strange problem where i cannot place the cursor on dynamic textbox when left clicked. But if i right click on it and then left click again, then the cursor appears on it. I just want to understand how this cursor appear on a textbox? is it because of the focus which happen when left click on it? I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks in advance

EDIT: in fiddle its working fine. I dunno what's wrong with my app.

```
<div class="icon" id="icon">
<div class="gloss"></div>
```

```
$('.icon').on('click', function (event) {

 event.stopPropagation();

                  var attrId=$(this).attr('id');
                  var parentCloneId=$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");



                  if($(this).hasClass("selected"+attrId)) {
                     $(".pop"+attrId).slideFadeToggle(function() {

                          $("#"+attrId).removeClass("selected"+attrId);
                          $("#config"+attrId).children(".pop"+attrId).remove(); 

                     }); 
                  } else {

                      var selectOptions="";

                      selectOptions+='<option value="1">1</option>';
                       selectOptions+='<option value="2">2</option>';
                       selectOptions+='<option value="3">3</option>';
                       selectOptions+='<option value="4">4</option>';
                      alert(4);
                      $(this).addClass("selected"+attrId).parent().append('<div id="pop' + attrId + '" class="messagepop pop' + attrId + '"><form id="new_message" action="/messages"><p><label for="definedStream">Please select the stream</label>'+
                                '<select name="selectedStreamsId' + attrId + '" id="selectedStreamsId' + attrId + '"><option value="-1">--SELECT--</option>'+selectOptions+
                                '</select></p>'+
                                '<p></p><input type="button" value="Save" name="saveStream' + attrId + '" id="saveStream' + attrId + '"/></div></form>');


                        $(".pop"+attrId+"").click(function(event) {

                        event.stopPropagation();


                    });

                  }




});
```

Check the link **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2qCY/1/)**

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle for that.

Comment: I will upload one in a bit

Comment: I don't see a textbox being added. Do you mean Dropdown?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention.it happens to both text boxes and drop downs.

Comment: Hi, please refer to this thread, i managed to make the fiddle with the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987853/left-click-does-not-work-on-dynamic-selectbox-textbox