# Left click does not work on dynamic selectbox/textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onclick, focus

i actually asked this question in another thread but i could not provide the fiddle example properly with the problem. Now i managed to create the fiddle example with the problem. Please follow the sequence where drag and drop the image to right side pane -> double click on the dropped image (then another image will appear where i did not included the src properly. but it does not matter) -> again click on the appeared image -? then the dynamic html will appear. Problem is when i try to left click on the selectbox it will not show the list of results. But when you right click on it and then left click on it, then it will appear. Please tell me the cause of it. I tried but i could not find it.

I will include part of code below but the full code will be there on fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;
    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stop: function (ev, ui) {

            var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
            var dragItem = $(this).attr('id');
            objName = "#" + dragItem + count;

            $(objName).removeClass("drag");

            $(objName).draggable({
                cancel: ".arrows"
            });


            //Fires when an existing object is dragged
            $(objName).draggable({
                containment: '#droppable',
                drag: function (ev, ui) {

                    // instance.repaint($(this)); 
                    var x = ui.offset.left;
                    var y = ui.offset.top;
                    $("#xax").val(x);
                    $("#yax").val(y);
                },
                stop: function (ev, ui) {

                    var x = ui.offset.left;
                    var y = ui.offset.top;

                    jsonElements.forEach(function (element) {

                        if (element.cloneID == currDragId) {
                            element.left = x;
                            element.top = y;

                            //appendNewArrowPositions(x,y,currDragId);
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        },
        revert: true
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        activeClass: "drop-area",
        drop: function (e, ui) {

            if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {

                count++;
                var dragItem = $(ui.draggable)[0].id;
                x = ui.helper.clone();
                $(this).append(x.attr("id", dragItem + count));

                ui.helper.remove();
                var clone = ui.draggable;
                var width = clone.width();
                var height = clone.height();

                var parent = $('.droppable.ui-droppable');

                //substract the additional amount created by relativeness
                var leftAd = (x.position().left - parent.offset().left);

                x.css({
                    left: leftAd
                });

                var offsetXPos = ui.offset.left;
                var offsetYPos = ui.offset.top;
                var obj = {};

                obj["cloneID"] = dragItem + count;
                obj["width"] = 85;
                obj["height"] = 85;
                obj["top"] = offsetYPos;
                obj["left"] = offsetXPos;

                if (dragItem == "input") {

                    obj["streamAlies"] = "";
                    obj["selectedDefinedStream"];
                    obj["asignedAttributeList"];
                    obj["itemType"] = "input";
                }
                var str = eval(obj);
                jsonElements.push(str);

                //to append the delete button only to the clone
                $('img[id="arrow"]').append($(x.find('img[id="arrow"]')).attr("id", 'cloneImage' + count));

                x.resizable({
                    maxHeight: $('#droppable').height(),
                    maxWidth: $('#droppable').width()
                });
                x.addClass('remove');

                var el = $('<span><a href="Javascript:void(0)" class=\"xicon delete' + count + '\" id=\"delete' + count + '\" title=\"Remove\">X</a></span>');
                $(el).insertAfter($('img[id="cloneImage' + count + '"]'));
                $("#" + dragItem + count).dblclick(function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    var cloneAttrID = $(this).attr('id');
                    var config = $('<span id=\"configconfigImg' + count + '\" class=\"config\"> <img id=\"configImg' + count + '\" class=\"configs configClone' + cloneAttrID + '\" src=\"images/configSymbol.png\"></span>');
                    $("#" + cloneAttrID).append(config);

                    $('.configClone' + cloneAttrID).on('click', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        var attrId = $(this).attr('id');
                        var parentCloneId = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
                        if ($(this).hasClass("selected" + attrId)) {
                            $(".pop" + attrId).slideFadeToggle(function () {
                                $("#" + attrId).removeClass("selected" + attrId);
                                $("#config" + attrId).children(".pop" + attrId).remove();
                            });
                        } else {
                            if (dragItem == "input") {
                                var selectOptions = "";
                                for (var z = 0; z < definedStreams.length; z++) {
                                    selectOptions += '<option value="' + definedStreams[z].streamName + '">' + definedStreams[z].streamName + '</option>';
                                }
                                jsonElements.forEach(function (element) {
                                    if (element.itemType == "Output") {
                                        selectOptions += '<option value="' + element.streamAlies + '">' + element.streamAlies + '</option>';
                                    }

                                });

                                $(this).addClass("selected" + attrId).parent().append('<div id="pop' + attrId + '" class="messagepop pop' + attrId + '"><form id="new_message" action="/messages"><p><label for="definedStream">Please select the stream</label>' +
                                    '<select name="selectedStreamsId' + attrId + '" id="selectedStreamsId' + attrId + '"><option value="-1">--SELECT--</option>' + selectOptions +
                                    '</select></p>' +
                                    '<p></p><input type="button" value="Save" name="saveStream' + attrId + '" id="saveStream' + attrId + '"/></div></form>');
                                //  Stopping propagation of specfic element
                                //$(".pop"+attrId).add('#selectedStreamsId'+attrId+'').click(handler);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                x.appendTo('#droppable');
            };
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/q2qCY/7/

Comment: i updated the fiddle link again and also in firefox only it works when right click and left clicked. other browsers it wont work for any clicks

Comment: Too much code for me... Also your problem seems unclear. "when i try to left click on the selectbox it will not show the list of results. But when you right click on it and then left click on it, then it will appear."?

Comment: Run the fiddle on firefox and excute the sequence i mentioned above. When the dynamic html appers, first left click on it. But it will not show the results. Results means when you normally left click on a select box you will see the options right. But here it will not show the options. But again right click on the selectbox and left click on it again. then you will see the options. This happens in firefox. Other browsers even right click and left click combination does not work. Hope you understand the problem.I will try to reduce the code.Thanks

Comment: i updated the fiddle.. I'm sorry if its too much code. I don't think i can reduce much further. Please forgive me for that and help me on this. I'm baffled by this problem.

Comment: What is slideFadeToggle in `$(".pop"+attrId).slideFadeToggle(function() {` supposed to do? It throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function .

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the function. Please check the updated fiddle link, funcntion will fadeout the dynamic html

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this. I'm really stuck on this...

Comment: I found the issue ,   $(objName).draggable({cancel: ".arrows"}); function causes it. theres no class called arrows in my code which I added before. and i forgot to remove it. Thanks guys who looked into it...:)